# How to do session management in liferay portlet?

Tags: json, portlet, liferay-6

One "Search" button is there in the JSP page. After taking all values for searching, the form is submitting.

In `processAction()`, I am getting all parameters. Using these parameters, in `doView()` I am consuming one API (`JSON` data). Creating one `JSON` object for input to the API and consuming it. Now I got the output `JSON` data and have passed it to the jsp using `renderRequest.setAttribute("jsonString", json.toString());`

Then showing search result using this `jsonString`.

Its working properly.

The issue is, its not creating multiple instances for multiple users. If one user done a search action, the same search result will show to each user if they refresh the page.
Why each user not having separate instances?

Now all users of this page can't do search action as they wish. If one user does, the same result will be shown to all. How can I fix it?

Why session of a particular user is sharing to all? Or What is the actual reason of this issue?

Comment: where are you using `session`? I can only see that you are using `renderRequest` and not `session`.

Comment: Yes..After doing search action some "Sessionid" is generating in the URL. So I thought its something related to session. Later I understood that what ever parameters we are setting in the doView() method, it is common to all clients..(it will share for all users). So what I did is, instead of setting parameters from doView(), done it from processAction() itself by using actionRequest.getPortletSession().setAttribute("name", value, PortletSession.PORTLET_SCOPE);. Now its working fine.